# C++ Fantasy Football Draft Program - Adding Players to Teams

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am working on making a C++ program that will simulate a fantasy football draft.. I have used a linked list to create a list of team names, for each person participating in the draft.  Now, I would like to know which way I should go about adding the players a team drafts to their respective team.  I have the football players in a read in file and can figure out how to let them choose which, but cannot figure out how to store them on their respective team.

Any help appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Random Tip: You might want to take a look at the public API for Yahoo's fantasy sports system. It presents a nice example of a working draft system, and you could easily do worse than cribbing off their object-class structure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you ought to have a Team class; the Team class ought to have a container to hold player names (another linked list, let's say). The list you have now should hold Teams rather than Strings.

Eventually the list of player names will probably be upgraded to a list of Player objects -- yet another class you'll want to define.

I know this is vague, but does it help?

Comment: Yes I believe I understand somewhat what you are saying, but after they insert their team names, how would I go about storing these into another class?

Comment: When you are letting Bob choose players, you would want to have Bob's "Team" object available; call it bobsTeam. As Bob chooses each player, you call bobsTeam.addPlayer(name); the implementation of addPlayer() would internally call push_back() on the vector<string> of player names to add the new player.

Comment: I understand the whole add player thing, so I am assuming you are saying to store each draftable player in a string of vectors?  And how would I go about re-calling Bob's team, then say Joe's team next, because I will not know the names being used until the user inputs these names.. ? I hope that made sense.

Comment: The Team object could store its own name as well, in addition to its players. Possibly passing the name to the constructor, when you create a new Team object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need to understand the basic C++ containers a bit better.

One way might be to simply remove the player from a list or array of all players in the league, and add it to the fantasy player's list or array of players.

```
class Player; // ...

class FantasyPlayer
{
public:
  std::vector< Player > picks; // array of my picks
};

std::vector< Player >         all_players;     // all available picks
std::vector< FantastyPlayer > fantasy_players; // all pickers

int iPicked = ...; // index of picked player in all_players
int iPicker = ...; // index of fantasy player currently picking

// add picked player to this fantasy player's pick list
fantasy_players[iPicker].picks.push_back(all_players[iPicked]);

// remove picked player from available players list
all_players.erase(iPicked);
```

Another, maybe easier, way to handle it might be to reference the "pickers" directly from the players themselves.

```
class FantasyPlayer; // ...

class Player
{
public:
  Player() : owner(0) { /* empty */ }
  FantastyPlayer* owner; // pointer to fantasy player who picked me
};

std::vector< Player >         all_players;     // all available picks
std::vector< FantastyPlayer > fantasy_players; // all pickers


int iPicked = ...; // index of picked player in all_players
int iPicker = ...; // index of fantasy player currently picking

// create link between a player and its picker
all_players[iPicked].owner = &(fantasy_players[iPicker]);
```

This code is all intentionally brief and incomplete, but maybe it'll get you started in the right direction. Good luck!